# How to simplify repetitive list comprehensions in python?

Tags: python, syntax, refactoring, list-comprehension

This code computes smallest rectangle containing a list of input rectangles:

```
left = min(x.left for x in rect)
bottom = min(x.bottom for x in rect)
right = max(x.right for x in rect)
top = max(x.top for x in rect)
```

I'm sure this can be simplified to single line statement but honestly I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you don't need *list*-comprehensions at all. You could just use genexps: `min(x.left for x in rect)`. This avoids creating a list object.

Comment: @Bakuriu - yes, that's better (corrected) but still not DRY enough.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that using list-comprehensions you are wasting space. However I still don't have clear if you care for the *performance* of that loop or you simply want to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a generator expression here, just loop *once*, updating minimi and maximi in one go:

```
left = bottom = float('inf')
right = top = float('-inf')
for x in rect:
    if x.left < left:     left = x.left
    if x.bottom < bottom: bottom = x.bottom
    if x.right > right:   right = x.right
    if x.top > top:       top = x.top
```

Yes, this is more verbose, but also *more efficient*. The longer `it` is, the less work the above loop performs compared to your 4 generator expressions.

You can produce *dictionaries* of results:

```
minimi = dict.fromkeys(('left', 'bottom'), float('inf'))
maximi = dict.fromkeys(('right', 'top'), float('-inf'))
for x in rect:
    for key in minimi:
        if getattr(x, key) < minimi[key]: minimi[key] = getattr(x, key)
    for key in maximi:
        if getattr(x, key) > maximi[key]: maximi[key] = getattr(x, key)
```

but that's hardly worth the abstraction, not for 2 values each.

Comment: I'd prefer: `left = min(left, x.left)` etc. avoiding all the `if`s... surely you pay 4 function calls which can be expensive, but I find it more readable.

Comment: @Bakuriu: That'd mean you call a function and assign 4 times every loop. Just testing is going to be faster. The OP is doing this inside a nested `for` loop, compounding the difference.

Comment: OK, I thought there can be a single list comprehension, equivalent to one loop, but more concise...

Comment: @mnowotka: No, a list comprehension always produces *one* list. You can split out rows in to columns with `zip()` but you'd still end up with 4 loops to determine separate minima and maxima.

Comment: @mnowotka, what you mean is to create 4 lists out of one comprehension... and AFAIK there is no such a thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what about using ternaries to "compress" the code in a more elegant way?

Comment: @ikaros45: You mean to test against an external variable in the list comprehension loop? *shudder*. That'll get **really, really ugly**. I much prefer explicit looping.

Comment: @ikaros45: List comprehensions are a lovely tool, but you should not try and cram all loops into one just for the sake of using a list comprehension. We are *not* producing a list result here, only minimi and maximi.

Comment: Have you actually timed this, though? This approach has the disadvantage that the actual looping process must be interpreted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: and what makes you think the generator expression is not a loop to be interpreted?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: But yes, this has been timed many times before.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Example: [How can I get the minimum and the maximum element of a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16938176)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: uhm, which actually contradicts my statements, but that test had straight lists to work with, not generator expressions. :-P.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, what I meant was just your first proposal, but instead of inline ifs, just ternary operators.

Comment: @ikaros45: right, but that would still invoke an assignment for every loop for all 4 variables. For most values, my version just tests, and only rarely assigns.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with a reduction, but it's probably less efficient than Martijn Pieters suggestion.

```
from functools import reduce

def fn(current_mins_maxs, r):
    z = zip(current_mins_maxs, (r.left, r.bottom, r.right, r.top))
    return [min(z[0]), min(z[1]), max(z[2]), max(z[3])]

first, rest = rectangles[0], rectangles[1:]
# Or, if you are using Python 3, you can write:
# first, *rest = rectangles
mins_and_maxs = reduce(fn, rest, (first.left, first.bottom, first.right, first.top))
```

Comment: @Martijn: the reduction only traverses the list once, the OP's code traverses the list four times.

Comment: Ah, no, I misunderstood what your `rectangles` list is. It's the same as the `rect` list in the edited post.